# Barcode generation libraries for Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, barcode

is there any barcode generation libraries for Delphi (prefered freeware of course), which generate most known barcode types (Code 39, Code 93, EAN, UPC)?

Comment: Did you ask Google (http://www.google.se/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Delphi+barcode)? I get http://www.download3000.com/delphi-barcode-downloads.html, http://www.zornsoftware.com/barcomp/, http://www.dlsoft.com/barcodes_in/barcodes_in_delphi.htm, http://stilius.net/tbarcode/, http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Programming/Delphi_Tools_and_Components/TBarcode_for_Delphi.html, http://www.vclcomponents.com/catalog/Delphi_Barcode, and http://www.han-soft.com/barcode.php, among a lot of other pages.

Comment: Why do you prefer freeware? Do you have any quality requirements?

Comment: @David I want to see the code and learn from that :) No quality requirements

Comment: access to source is not the same as freeware

Comment: here is one: http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=1836

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The old TurboPower SysTools (available from SourceForge) does POSTNET, UPC A, UPC E, EAN 13, EAN 8, Interleaved 2 of 5, Codabar, Code 11, Code 39, Code 93, and Code 128.

It was open sourced when TP went out of the VCL business. You can download it (along with the usual great TP documentation in both PDF and WinHelp format. I also seem to recall it was ported to D2009+ and is available at [SongBeamer](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/).

Comment: The SongBeamer ports to Delphi2009+ are excellent quality.

Answer (score 1):

Most Delphi Reporting Components [Fast Reports, Rave Reports, and others] supports barcodes in their report designers.  They are NOT free.