# Delphi QR Code component / generator?

Tags: delphi, qr-code

I am desperately looking for a QR Code component to generate QR Code. So far the only method I have found is through Google API chart but I need an offline method.
http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/generating-qr-codes-with-delphi/

I cannot find any component, free or not, that can generate QR code. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: There are *many* such components. Have you asked Google? I did on [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008544/barcode-generation-libraries-for-delphi).

Comment: I guess my search was too narrow (I was looking at QR Code), instead of looking at generally 2D barcode, which can include QR Code. That's why all my searched were unsuccessful and I did not see your questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here we go:

http://www.han-soft.com/barcode2dgen.php

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [han-soft.com](http://www.han-soft.com/images/barcode2dgen_b.gif))</sub>

I just aksed Google. First hit, basically.

It is available as a VCL component, here:

http://www.han-soft.com/barcode2d.php

Comment: ok now I look stupid, I've searched for an hour. just so I can tell myself I'm not *that* bad a googling, what are the terms you have used?

Comment: @BeachBoy: I tried ["Delphi barcode"](http://www.google.se/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Delphi+barcode). The first page is [this](http://www.download3000.com/delphi-barcode-downloads.html). The first item at this page is [Barcode VCL component](http://www.download3000.com/download_3284.html), and the official webpage of the component is [this](http://www.han-soft.com/barcode.php) [search for "Developer: Han-soft Software"]. Now click "2D Barcode VCL Components" to get to http://www.han-soft.com/barcode2d.php.

Answer (score 13):

The company I work for has released an open source (Apache License v2) [Delphi QR barcode generator](http://www.debenu.com/open-source/delphizxingqrcode/) called DelphiZXingQRCode. It's a Delphi port of the QR code functionality from the [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) barcode image processing library.

Answer (score 5):

Just discovered (months late, however) [ZINT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/).  A Pascal wrapper for this exists [here](http://theunknownones.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Components/ZintBarcode/). This is free, open source.

Answer (score 1):

Another one is at http://www.java4less.com/barcodedelphi/barcodesdelphi.php

I just bought it this week, and took about 1 hour to incorporate QR code generation into my app (and it's pure Delphi code: no DLL).