# Generate barcode

Tags: delphi, barcode, zxing

hi is there any known Delphi library to generate/decode [QR Code Generator from the ZXing](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) Project?

thanx in advance..

Comment: There's no free Delphi library based on ZXing. I don't know if the paying libs are based on it or not...

Comment: what does this code generator do that other QR libraries don't? Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196848/delphi-qr-code-component-generator) help?

Comment: Generate or decode? They're opposites. Which do you want?

Comment: i want to generate a barcode.

Comment: Here are some free Libraries or components:

http://delphi32.blogspot.com/2011/11/quricol-qr-code-generator-library.html

http://theunknownones.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Components/ZintBarcode/

Yo may also want to take a look at this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/

Comment: no, actually there is a ZXIng porting for delphi (and can be compiled on all delphi supported architectures (Win32,Win64, ios, osx, android..): https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi/tree/v_3.0