# QR-Code Component for Delphi

Tags: delphi, qr-code

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Delphi QR Code component / generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196848/delphi-qr-code-component-generator)
>   [Barcode generation libraries for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008544/barcode-generation-libraries-for-delphi)

The only one I found is http://www.han-soft.com/barcode2d.php
Can you suggest other components?

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's not clear what you're looking for - I think you might be looking for a QuickReport component for bar-codes, but I'm not sure. Please edit your question and expand on what exactly it is you're asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [tec-it](http://www.tec-it.com/de/software/barcode-software/tbarcode/overview/Default.aspx) software. They have a DLL wich can be used from Delphi but I havn't used it up to now.